# Access "private" variables in prototype

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in JavaScript to create a private variable which can be accessed in prototype? I tried the following which [obviously doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/TBfk4/), because `bar` is only accessible from within `Foo`  and not from within prototype.

```
function Foo() {
    var bar = 'test';
}

Foo.prototype.baz = function() {
    console.log(bar);
};
```

I know I also cannot use `this.bar = 'test'`, because that would make [the property public](http://jsfiddle.net/KrAXh/) AFAIK. How to make the `bar` variable private, but accessible by prototype?

Comment: Not unless you return it (which means it isn't exactly private, but still is)!

Comment: What do you mean by "public"? What's your use case for this?

Comment: @AndyRay The use case is encapsulation in general and how it is handled in JavaScript in specific.

Comment: If you're not instantiating Foo with new then you can just do Foo.prototype.bar = 'whatever'; and Foo.bar won't exist. But if you do var q = new Foo(); then q.bar will exist

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't - it's impossible to access a lexically scoped variable from outside that scope.

Prototype methods are (by definition) shared between all instances, and to do so must exist in their own scope.

Douglas Crockford's article [*Private Members in JavaScript*](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) provides some useful explanations, but no solution that meets your requirements.

Comment: It _is_ possible (and not even hard) to create a variable accessible to _some_ methods within the prototype.

Comment: Care to elaborate on this? @JanDvorak Or am I just doing something stupid and is this just not how JavaScript should work?

Comment: Apologies, my variables would be "class" variables, not "instance" variables. That's not what's requested. I was thinking of privileged methods - moving them to the prototype would create "static" variables. Upvoting.